# CassandraOperations: QueryBuilder.token issue

Tags: cassandra, query-builder, spring-data-cassandra

I am using `CassandraTemplate` to get data from Cassandra DB. I am trying to build a query using `QueryBuilder` and here is what I am trying to build ...

```
select * from users where token(user, timebucket) > token('222233111',20151231) ;
```

I have followed [this link](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-44) and did the same ...

```
Select select = select().all().from("users");
select.where(QueryBuilder.gt(QueryBuilder.token("user","timebucket"), myToken(userId,bucketime)));
users = cassandraOperations.select(select, Users.class);
```

but still my query is getting generated like

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE token(user,timebucket)>'token(222233111, 20151231)';
```

I am getting below error, please help me on how to build my query successfully.

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Expected 8 or 0 byte long (26)
```

### ADDED MyToken code ...

```
 private String myToken(String... values) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("token(");
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if (i > 0)
            sb.append(", ");
        sb.append(values[i]);
    }
    sb.append(")");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: what is myToken ?

Comment: added the code for myToken